# Calculate percentage of returned items of last order

Tags: r

Data:

```
DB <- data.frame(orderID  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),     
orderDate = c("1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","2.1.14", "2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14"),  
itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),  
price = c(29.90, 39.90, 29.90, 19.90, 49.90, 9.90, 29.90, 39.90, 14.90, 19.90),
customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
ItemReturned = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Expected outcome:

```
percentageOfReturnedItemsLastOrder = c(0.33, 0.5, 0, 0.33, 0.33, 0,  0.5, 0.5, 0.33, 0.33)
```

Hi guys,
unfortunately I have another problem I´m not able to solve alone - so I would be very pleased if you peeps help me again :) In the data set every order got its own id and every registered user has his unique customerID. Every customer can order items (with ItemIDs), which got specific prices. The column "ItemReturned" shows if the item returned to the shop ("1") or if the customer kept the item at home ("0)  I want to calculate the percentage of the items which returned to shop from last order . I also want to add the results as new columns in my existing data set...

Tried it already with data table but I must have made a mistake - cause it´s not working ;)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DB)[, orderDate := as.Date(orderDate, format = "%d.%m.%y")]
DB[, `:=` (percentageOfReturnedItemsLastOrder  = sum(ItemRetuned> 0[orderDate == max(orderDate)])), by = customerID]
```

Hope your able to show me what´s wrong or show me another posibility to solve the prob....

Cheers and THX!

Comment: Your date formatting is wrong. It should be something like `setDT(DB)[, orderDate := as.Date(orderDate, format = "%d.%m.%y")]` though I'm not sure if your date is d.m.y or m.d.y

Comment: Also what's `returnShipment`? you don't have such column

Comment: sorry buddy: its not return shipment - it´s ItemReturned:etited now my mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
DB[, percentageOfReturnedItemsLastOrder := 
     sum(ItemReturned[orderDate == max(orderDate)])/length(ItemReturned[orderDate == max(orderDate)]), 
   by = customerID]

#     orderID  orderDate itemID price customerID ItemReturned percentageOfReturnedItemsLastOrder
#  1:       1 2014-01-01      2  29.9          1            0                          0.3333333
#  2:       2 2014-01-01      3  39.9          2            0                          0.5000000
#  3:       3 2014-01-01      2  29.9          3            0                          0.0000000
#  4:       4 2014-01-01      5  19.9          1            1                          0.3333333
#  5:       5 2014-01-02     12  49.9          1            1                          0.3333333
#  6:       6 2014-01-02      4   9.9          3            0                          0.0000000
#  7:       7 2014-01-02      2  29.9          2            1                          0.5000000
#  8:       8 2014-01-02      3  39.9          2            0                          0.5000000
#  9:       9 2014-01-02      1  14.9          1            0                          0.3333333
# 10:      10 2014-01-02      5  19.9          1            0                          0.3333333
```

Comment: Tried it, but its not working: That´s the text of the error :"Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('integer'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)"

Comment: customerID is a factor; orderDate is a date; ItemReturned is an Integer - maybe that´s the problem...

Comment: Do you already have `percentageOfReturnedItemsLastOrder` in your data? Then remove because it's incorrect. Than run my code. You also weren't converting to date correctly, see my first comment